# How to set request interceptor in SwaggerUIBundle?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

In our **swagger.json** we are setting basePath to **/api**, however, when the application is deployed in docker container, the context path is not /api. This could be different thing and we don't know what it is so we can't hard code it.

I am trying to set **requestInterceptor** as per the following guide, in order to catch the request and modify the url path perhaps:

https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#customization-36

But it seems **requestInterceptor** is being ignored. Is this possible? If not, how can I set the correct path at runtime?

This is my code in **index.html**

```
    window.onload = function() {
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "../api-docs/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    requestInterceptor: function(request) {
        window.alert(request);
    },
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })

  window.ui = ui

}
```

We are using **Swagger 2.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version from [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), or update your node package. I had the same problem because I downloaded the distribution before `requestInterceptor` support was added.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily upgrade before approval from technical team but the question is, is my solution going to work if I do the upgrade? Can I set the host and context path on the fly?